# Cannot Print Variable Value that Was Incremented in Loop

Tags: c, loops, scope

I am currently trying to learn the C programming language and am using Kernighan and Ritchie's *The C Programming Language, Second Edition*. I am trying to write a program similar to an example they give in the book in chapter one regarding text streams.

My program is supposed to print out a text file to the terminal and then count the number of characters before printing that figure too. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0, c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        count++;
        putchar(c);
    }

    printf("\n%d characters\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
This is a simple file
With two very small lines
I mean three
1 characters
```

But when I add in this line below `count++`:

```
printf("%d", count);
```

The result is:

```
1T2h3i4s5 6i7s8 9a10 11s12i13m14p15l16e17 18f19i20l21e22
23W24i25t26h27 28t29w30o31 32v33e34r35y36 37s38m39a40l41l42 43l44i45n46e47s48
49I50 51m52e53a54n55 56t57h58r59e60e61
1 characters
```

This means that count is being incremented, but I cannot access its value from outside of the while loop. I thought that if the declaration of the variable (in this case `int count = 0` is outside the loop), then the value could still be reached after the loop.

If it makes a difference, this is what I call it with:

```
./example <text.txt
```

Am I making a silly mistake? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Update**

I do not know if it makes a difference, but the compiler I am using is: powerpc-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1. Is that what the problem is?

**Update 2**

This is the command I used to compile the source: `gcc -Wall example.c -o example`. A weird thing has just happened though. It worked perfectly when I ran this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0, c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        count++;
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("x");
    printf("\n%d characters\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
This is a simple file
With two very small lines
I mean three
61 characters
```

The only difference between this code and the code above is the `printf("x")` line. I don't understand why it suddenly works if I print something else and I don't understand why it isn't visible. Any character can be put in the command and the same result happens. If more than one character is added, then the second one, and any after that, is printed.

Comment: I get 60 characters for your example file and I don't see anything wrong with your code. Make sure this is the code you're actually running.

Comment: The code is absolutely correct. It works for me

Comment: @mafso From information on the internet and in the book, it seemed correct to me too, but for some reason it is not working. It is definitely the same code that I am running.

Comment: No, it definitely isn't. Delete all object files and executables. Check your source code. Save the file. Compile again. Maybe show how you compile and don't use `make` or the like, to narrow down the problem.

Comment: if you add `printf("%d", count);` to your code below `count++;` you would not get the `61` after the last character

Comment: @mch I thought that too, but that was the output it gave out. I figure there must just be an empty space saved at the end of the text file

Comment: In the output you gave, there is no trailing space. Did you copy and paste?

Comment: If there is an empty space at the end of the file, it's easy to find: Place an output statement before the loop, outputting `'"'`, and one after the loop as well. That way you will see if there are extra spaces or tabs at the end of the last line.

Comment: The output didn't contain the `x` for your working version? Can you give a hexdump of the input file? There is some suspicious 61-st byte at the end…

Comment: it works even with an extra space at the end: https://ideone.com/vtHuWT have you tried to compile with some optimization? like `-O3` or so?

Comment: Take your first code snippet. Replace putchar(c) with printf("(%d)\n",c). What's the output?

Comment: I'm with @mafso, a hexdump would be good. There may be a byte that you are outputting with `putchar()` that causes the next character to not display.

Comment: So the "x" actually wasn't printed in your second example ?

Comment: Run it with a debugger and look at the value of `count` right before the call to `printf`.

Comment: Replace `putchar(c)` by `printf("%02x\n", c")` and show us the output. I suscpect some control character in your "text.txt" file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your reference of characters to where characters are stored in memory is incorrectly coded which is why your output comes out like that. Ensure that the file and text within are correctly referenced. Other than that, the code seems OK.

I think this is what you should do:

```
int count = 0, c;
FILE *file = fopen("example.txt", "r");

while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
    count++;
    putchar(c);
}

printf("\n%d characters\n", count);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean either, could you please elaborate?

Comment: What I mean't was that the aim was to read from a file. However, a file was not referenced in his code and therefore the results that were obtained are memory addresses. This is a typical thing that you will find in C if proper address referencing is not done especially when using pointers and references.

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing a `fflush(stdout)` immediately before the 
    `printf("\n%d characters\n", count);`

FYI: your origninal code executes as expected on Ubuntu 14.04 Linux.